# I am facing Spring boot Update query error with hibernate5 and MySql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I want to "update" the table using the query, but having error
"class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode (org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode and org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @1cd201a8)"

```
    @Override
    @Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    public void setCount() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class); 
       
      
        Query<TtRequest> query = currentSession.createQuery("update TtRequest" + " set count = 
        :id" + " 
         where msisdn2 = :ms", TtRequest.class);
        
        query.setParameter("id", 0);
        query.setParameter("ms", 1557692442);
        
        
         query.executeUpdate();
    
    
    }

I have also used the changed code below and have an error

"expecting "set", found '.' near line 1, column 15 [update new com.example.topupsendbox.entity.TtRequest set count = :id where msisdn2 = :ms]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "set", found '.' near line 1, column 15 [update new com.example.topupsendbox.entity.TtRequest set count = :id where msisdn2 = :ms]"
 

@Override
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
public void setCount() {
        Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Query<TtRequest> query = currentSession.createQuery("update new 
           com.example.topupsendbox.entity.TtRequest" + " set count = :id" + 
        " where msisdn2 = :ms", TtRequest.class);

        query.setParameter("id", 0);
        query.setParameter("ms", 1557692442);
        query.executeUpdate();

   }
```

How I can solve the error for Update the code

Answer (score 0):

For bulk/native update use createSQLQuery(). Which will update multiple rows or columns.

```
@Override
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
public void setCount() {
    Session currentSession = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class); 
    currentSession.createSQLQuery("update TtRequest" + " set count = :id" + "  where 
    msisdn2 = :ms", TtRequest.class).setParameter("id", 0).setParameter("ms", 
    1557692442).executeUpdate();
    
  }
```

It worked for me.